If $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=4$, what's the maximum value of $a+b+c+d$?
This is from an inequality in Samin Riasat's book. It's:

$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{d}+\frac{d^2}{a}\geq4$

Given $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=4$. Rearranging and using Cauchy-Schwarz I've reduced it to

$\sqrt{68} - 2 ≥ a + b + c + d$

Testing on desmos, I haven't been able to get $a+b+c+d\geq4$, so the inequality is probably true, the question is, how do I prove it? If you could do so or give me a hint, I'd really appreciate it, thanks.

Welcome to MSE!  As you are a new contributor to the site. I suggest you read some basic information about writing mathematics at this site, see, e.g. How can I format mathematics, There should be universal LaTeX/MathJax guide for sites supporting it, and MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference

The answer must be at least 4, which can be achieved with $a=b=c=d=1$.

Try Lagrange Multipliers.

Assuming $a,b,c,d \gt 0$ (otherwise said inequality is false). Then using Engel's form, a well known form of Cauchy Schwarz the result is obvious.

Clearly it is achieved when $a,b,c,d$ are nonnegative. The quadratic mean inequality then gives $$\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}\leq\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{4}}=1.$$

We should also check that the other inequality given doesn't reduce the maximum - but that's easy since $(1,1,1,1)$ makes all three equal.

Let us write $w:=a-1,\,x:=b-1,\,y:=c-1,\,z:=d-1$. Then maximizing $a+b+c+d$ corresponds to maximizing $w+x+y+z$. Now
$$w+x+y+z=-\tfrac12(w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2).$$
This is maximized just when $w=x=y=z=0$, namely when $a+b+c+d=4$.

This is very nice.
